# Solution for Heat equation like Boundary problem solved with Sine or Cosine transform

Tags: fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem

I have this problem: 
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 u_{xx}= u_{t}+u && 0<x< +\infty  & t>0\\   
 u(x,0)=0 &&& x>0&\\ 
 u_{x}(0,t)=f(t)&&& t\geq 0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
I need to solve this problem with sine and cosine transforms, the definition used for sine and cosine transforms are the following ones:

$Fc(f)(w)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) cos(wx)dx$

$Fs(f)(w)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) sin(wx)dx$

and the antitransforms are:

$Fc^{-1}(f)(w)= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(w) cos(wx)dw$

$Fs^{-1}(f)(w)= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(w) sin(wx)dw$

I tried to think about taking the sine transform on both sides of the differential equation, then:

$\hat{u}(w,t)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} u(x,t) sin(wx)dx$

$\hat{u}_{xx}(w,t)=-(w)^{2}\hat{u}(w,t)$

$\hat{u}_{t}(w,t)=\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}(w,t)$

So, when I replace that in the differential equation:

$-(w)^{2}\hat{u}(w,t)=\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}(w,t) + \hat{u}(w,t)$

The solution is:

$\hat{u}(w,t)=A(w)e^{(-1-w²)t}$

But then if $t=0$

$\hat{u}(w,0)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} u(x,0) sin(wx)dx=0$

$\hat{u}(w,0)=A(w)=0$ (the trivial solution)

What should I do? There's no difference if I take the cosine transform.

Comment: The problem is that $Fc(u_{xx}) \neq -w^2 \hat{u}(w,t)$ as some boundary terms appears.

Comment: yes, it's "the function in 0 multiplied by w" term, but as you can see the funciton in 0 is 0 or I misunderstand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

As you have mentioned in your comments, we have:
$$Fc(f_x)=wFs(f)-f(0)$$
$$Fs(f_x)=-wFc(f)$$
so:
$$Fc(f_{xx})=wFs(f_{x})-f_{x}(0)=-w^2 Fc(f)-f_{x}(0)$$
$$Fs(f_{xx})=-wFc(f_{x})=-w^2 Fs(f)+w f(0)$$
and in your equation you obtain:
$$Fs(u_{xx})(w,t)=-w^2 Fs(u)(w,t)+w \times 0$$
$$Fc(u_{xx})(w,t)=-w^2 Fc(u)(w,t)(w,t)-\color{red}{ f(t)}$$
the red term is the one that generate an non zero solution.